# Display specific parent product attribute in Woocommerce cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I have an attribute of Metal Type assigned to my products but is not used as part of variations, I still want to get the Metal Type of each parent product and display it in the cart/checkout page.

To get the name of the selected Metal Type term I'm using the following:

```
$_product = $cart_item['data]'];
$parent_id = $_product->get_parent_id();
$parent_attributes = wc_get_product($parent_id)->get_attributes();
$term_id = $parent_attributes['pa_metal-type']['data']['options'][0];
$term = get_term_by('id', $termId, 'pa_metal-type');
$term_name = $term->name;
```

My attempt at using the woocommerce_get_item_data filter doesn't seem to be working, I know I'm making a mistake somewhere, I'm not experienced enough to know where though:

```
// Add metal type to cart line items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'get_metal_type', $cart_data, $cart_item );

function get_metal_type($cart_data, $cart_item) {

  $_product = $cart_item['data]'];
  $parent_id = $_product->get_parent_id();
  $parent_attributes = wc_get_product($parent_id)->get_attributes();
  $term_id = $parent_attributes['pa_metal-type']['data']['options'][0];
  $term = get_term_by('id', $termId, 'pa_metal-type');
  $term_name = $term->name;

  $custom_items = array();

  if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) { $custom_items = $cart_data; }

  if( !empty($term) ) {

      $custom_items[] = array(
          'key'   => 'Metal Type',
          'value' => $term_name,
        );

      return $custom_items;

  }
}
```

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making that much more complicated than it is. Try the following instead:

```
// Display the Meta type in cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_attribute_metal_type', 90, 2 );
function display_attribute_metal_type( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
        // Get the parent variable product object instance
        $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );

        // Get the "Metal type" product attribute term name
        $term_names = $product->get_attribute( 'metal-type' );

        if( isset($term_names) && ! empty($term_names) ){
            // Add "Metal type" data to be displayed
            $cart_item_data[] = array(
                'name' => __('Metal Type'),
                'value' => $term_names,
            );
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: tested the solution and it seems to be working great! I wasn't aware that I could get the attribute even though it's not assigned to the variation itself. In addition, working off your solution, for products with a single attribute (e.g. color), the function `wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data` doesn't seem to output the color attribute and its term, but for products with two attributes (e.g. color, size) the two attributes and their terms are outputted.